# SEO Friendly URL like Magento

Tags: php, codeigniter, magento, model-view-controller

We are developing an eCommerce store using CodeIgniter framework.

We need category management module, is it possible? And I have one query example below:

```
www.xyz.com/jewelry/ring
```

This is default URL, we can update this URL like

```
www.xyz.com/jewelry/ring-for-man
```

Is it possible using CodeIgniter framework or MVC in PHP?

Comment: you can do this create slug for category and store that into database and by uri segment you can do this in codeigniter

Comment: Just go through this link. It may help you [cdeigniter routing seo friendly](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-method-to-make-CodeIgniter-URLs-SEO-friendly)

Comment: You can do use routing in cakephp also , similar feature is there is codeigniter , in case of cakephp we have http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: from old url to new url display on admin module where we can update old url to new url which is redirect automatically so i want create this type of module so is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this route in your `/application/config/routes.php` file

```
$route['jewelry/(.*)'] = 'products/jewelry/$1';
```

So, your final url will be `jewelry/ring` with `product` controller class and `jewelry` function with parameter `ring` called.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
codeigniter provide url routing [url routing for codeigniter 3.x](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) and [url routing for codeigniter 2.x](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html)
Both are almost same.

You need something like this

```
$route['jewelry/ring'] = 'products/ring-for-man';
```